# How to access log files of neo4j deployed to aws ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, neo4j

I have deployed neo4j to ec2 using this https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/ec2neo
I am getting 503 service not available error. How can I access the neo4j logs on ec2. Can anybody help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps to access the logs are given in: [ec2neo Output](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/ec2neo/blob/master/images/output.jpg)

Select the CloudFormation stack that you used to create the instance. Click on Outputs tab. It will give you the actual ssh command to use to access the EC2 instance.